# agent library failed to init: instrument

Tags: java, eclipse, virtual-machine, javaagents, closesocket

## The Problem

I'm currently attempting to use the debugger in Eclipse for the first time and received the following error: 
[image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQaBU.png)

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /media/david/Linux/Eclipse/eclipse-java-2021-03-R-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/216/0/.cp/lib/javaagent-shaded.jar
```

What could be the problem that I can not use the debugger and leading to this error?

## What I've tried

- Made sure the javaagent-shaded.jar file exists
- Made sure the path is correct
- Tried to start Eclipse with sudo
- Made sure Eclipse has access to the above mentioned path
- In `Debug Configuration -> Arguments` I tried to use this as a VM argument:

> -javaagent:/media/david/Linux/Eclipse/eclipse-java-2021-03-R-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/216/0/.cp/lib/javaagent-shaded.jar

- In `Debug Configuration -> Source` I tried to manually add the javaagent-shaded.jar with the path included

## The Environment

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Eclipse 2021-03
- openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20 
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04) 
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who has the same problem: I reinstalled eclipse and it worked perfectly fine afterwards.